# HTML to CMYK .pdf file for print

Tags: php, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I'm working on a new web application where users can drag and drop their own elements to create a printable design. The application then creates a .pdf file that is send to the printing studio, prints the design and sends to the customer.

Now as we know web browsers and HTML is working with RGB and printers prefer to use CMYK. Is there a way to create a .pdf file using CMYK from the HTML instead of RGB? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ABCpdf .NET will do this for you.

Use AddImageUrl/Html to insert your HTML into the PDF. Something along these lines:

```
Doc theDoc = new Doc();
int theID = theDoc.AddImageUrl("http://www.google.com");
while (true) {
    if (!theDoc.Chainable(theID)) break;
    theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
    theID = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theID);
}
```

Then use the RecolorOperation to convert the PDF to CMYK. Something like this:

```
RecolorOperation op = new RecolorOperation();
op.DestinationColorSpace = new ColorSpace(theDoc.ObjectSoup, ColorSpaceType.DeviceCMYK);
op.Recolor(theDoc);
```

Then save. Something like this:

```
theDoc.Save(@"c:\output.pdf");
```

My replies may feature concepts based around ABCpdf. It's what I work on. It's what I know. :-)

Comment: Sometimes CMYK has to be used to get an exact colour, for example a logo that is to be printed in pure Cyan. You will not achieve that when converting to CMYK as described above. You will however get a CMYK document, but most advanced printer software would to the same conversion today from sRGB, probably even better, since they will likely have more knowledge about the media that is to be printed on, and will be using a more correct conversion table (profile) – but don't count on a 100% Cyan only. You would have to start with CMYK objects in your document for that.